# mongodb - summations of array length with same ids

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am creating a platform where people can share their memes. On one page I want to show them who are the most popular members on the platform. so, there is a collection of 'meme' and 'user'

for example,

There is two content with same ids:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  username: "name",
  bio: "bio",
  image: "url",
};
```

memes

```
{
  _id: 0,
  user_id: 1,
  image: "meme1.jpg",
  likes: [
    {
      user_id: 4
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 1,
  user_id: 1,
  image: "meme2.jpg",
  likes: [
    {
      user_id: 5
    },
    {
      user_id: 6
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want to output something like this way

```
{
  user_id:1,
  username:"name"
  likes:3,
}
```

I wrote this query using aggregate functions but I am not understanding how to identify ids are the same or not?

```js
meme
  .aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "user_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "userDetails",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        user_id: "$user_id",
        username: "$userDetails.username",
        likes: {
          $size: "$likes",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { likes: 1 },
    },
  ])
  .exec()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to start query with users.

You can use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) aggregations to get the total likes, and add it using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/).

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "memes",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "userDetails"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "likes": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$userDetails",
            "in": {
              "$size": "$$this.likes"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user_id: "$_id",
      username: 1,
      likes: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pqGY3KuB6Sm)

Result:

```
[
  {
    "likes": 3,
    "user_id": 1,
    "username": "name"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you.can you tell me where you checking that id is the same or not? actually I am new NoSQL that's why

Comment: @Yashrajbasan which id  do you mean?

Comment: @Yashrajbasan this nicely answers your question, can you please mark and upvote the answer?

Comment: yeah I did that

Comment: @Yashrajbasan it still shows not marked. Can you check please? It seems you marked another answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could project the length of the `likes`-array and group each projection by the user_id and cound the results. Something like this should work:

```
db.getCollection('memes').aggregate([{
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                localField: "user_id",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "userDetails"
            }
        }, {
            "$project": {
                "user_id": 1,
                "likesSize": {
                    "$size": "$likes"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$user_id",
                "count": {
                    "$sum": "$likesSize"
                }

            }
        }
    ])
```

The above query should return:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "count" : 3
}
```